# iOS Phonegap Plugin for ZIPPING

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, zip, archive

I have a *iOS Phonegap project*. In which I have some heavy sized files. I want to ZIP these files within the **www** folder and would like to UNZIP this when the user clicks a button in the app.

This helps the app to be very condensed when the user downloads for the first time!

I would really love to have some suggestions or some Plugin guidance for this usage. If you can specifically give a direction it would really help! I tried using ZipUtil Plugin, ExtractPlugin from Phonegap Plugins but in vain! I know there should be a sample code which would guide us correctly and from where we can learn! Someone please help!

Comment: You want to unzip files in phone? this will kill phone's battery fast (and probably eating up storage too)!

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you will need this to UNZIP and ZIP

[Extract Zip File](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ExtractZipFile)

Comment: I tried this plugin but showed some errors when I tried to run it. I followed the Readme as it is mentioned in there. There are 2 Readme one in https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iOS/ExtractZipFile/SSZipArchive/Readme.markdown

and one in https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iOS/ExtractZipFile/README.md

I tried compiling using this plugin. My zip file lives locally and not online.

Comment: What errors _ did you read on how to import the plugin into your project ?

Comment: Lot of errors in xcode. I am using the latest xcode and 2.3 pg for ios. Can you please show a sample project file in Xcode.

Comment: With just "lots of errors", nobody will be able to help you. I am sure the plugin works.

Comment: Wouldnt post a Questionnaire if I dint have any hope with this site.

Comment: This issue has still been left unresolved for me. And I am still struggling. Can someone please recommend which plugin to use inorder for it to work with the latest PG and XCODE.

And also some guidance for the same how to integrate it.

Comment: Guide on how to use it with iPhone --> https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iOS/ExtractZipFile/SSZipArchive/Readme.markdown as for errors you should post some of the relevant code together with erros!,nobody can or is able to help you if you write "I have a bunch of errors"